# Django initialize database in a custom way when syncdb

Tags: database, django

I'm using Django in a development process. It is annoying that every time I change a bit in a model I need to delete database and run syncdb. For the purpose of testing, I want to add some initial data into database automatically every time when I run syncdb. I've tried put these sort of code inside one app's `__init__.py`, but it would run before database created and it's a bit annoying to deal with exceptions. Isn't there a neater way to do this?

Comment: Take a look to `loaddata` https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/#django-admin-loaddata

Comment: i'm trying to understand if your matter is due to a test database or what else exactly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you have initially populated the database; use the [`dumpdata`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/django-admin/#dumpdata-appname-appname-appname-model) command to create a fixture (a copy of data). Save it to a file. Then use the [`loaddata`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/django-admin/#loaddata-fixture-fixture) command to automatically populate the database.

Suppose you have an app called `bookstore` for which you want to automatically load a series of books, authors, etc.

Once you have added some records in the database:

```
python django-admin.py dumpdata bookstore > initial.json
```

Once you have made some changes or want to recreate the database:

```
python django-admin.py loaddata initial.json
```

South is nice, but it is overkill for this purpose.

Comment: exact that what i used to do. and that the best option

Answer (score 0):

If you need to make changes in database and you want that your data remains safe then [SOUTH](http://south.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html) is the right software for you.

It manages change in database and its data. You wont need to delete database when you make changes if you have South. Also it has backups of previous states of database so that if you want to revert back you can. I recommend you read its documentation. It will surely help.